# Using conditionals to count matching rows from two dataframes r

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have two dataframes, I want to count the number of times both have a result_gain of 1 in the same chr with the same start and stop number +/- probes.

here probes = 1000

So if dataframe1 had a result_gain of 1 at a start+/-probes and stop+/-probes at chr 5 at the same chr number and start+/-probes and stop+/-probes with a result_gain of 1 then I wish to count this, the method I have attached is not working, do you have any suggestions?

dataframe1

```
chr start   stop    result_gain result_loss result_cnloh
2   0   90247720    0   0   0
2   95627407    243199373   0   0   0
7   0   57789531    1   0   0
7   61760895    159138663   1   0   0
8   0   6974050 0   0   0
8   8102641 43646413    1   0   0
8   47060977    146364022   0   0   0
9   0   38771460    0   0   0
9   71034203    141213431   0   0   0
10  0   38685231    0   0   0
10  42810783    135534747   0   0   0
11  0   51530241    0   0   0
11  54835623    135006516   0   0   0
12  0   34768168    0   0   0
12  38416139    133851895   0   0   0
13  19263735    115169878   0   0   0
14  20213937    107349540   0   0   0
15  20161372    102531392   1   0   0
17  0   22175355    0   0   0
17  25375921    81195210    0   0   0
```

dataframe 2

```
chr start   stop    result_gain result_loss result_cnloh
2   0   90247720    1   0   0
2   95627407    243199373   0   0   0
7   0   57789531    1   0   0
7   61760895    159138663   1   0   0
8   0   6974050 0   0   0
8   8101641 43646413    1   0   0
8   47060977    146364022   0   0   0
9   0   38771460    0   0   0
9   71034203    141213431   0   0   0
10  0   38685231    0   0   0
10  42810783    135534747   0   0   0
11  0   51530241    0   1   0
11  54835623    135006516   0   0   0
12  0   34768168    0   0   0
12  38416139    133851895   0   0   0
13  19263735    115169878   0   0   0
14  20213937    107349540   0   0   0
15  20161372    102531392   1   0   0
17  0   22175355    0   0   0
17  25375921    81195210    0   0   0
```

here are the following matching rows from both
matching rows from dataframe1

```
7   0   57789531    1   0   0
7   61760895    159138663   1   0   0
8   8102641 43646413    1   0   0
15  20161372    102531392   1   0   0
```

matching rows from dataframe2

```
7   0   57789531    1   0   0
7   61760895    159138663   1   0   0
8   8101641 43646413    1   0   0
15  20161372    102531392   1   0   0
```

output

```
score = 4
```

After subsetting each chr for dataframe1 and dataframe2 I am using the following conditionals to count, but it does not work.

```
for (e in 1:nrow(gains_idcc)) {
     for (h in 1:nrow(gains_dciss)) {
          if (gains_dciss$start[e] <= (idcc$start[h] + probes_per_bp) | dciss$start[e] <= (idcc$start[h] - probes_per_bp) | dciss$start[e] == idcc$start[h] && dciss$stop[e] >= (idcc$stop[h] + probes_per_bp) | dciss$stop[e] >= (idcc$stop[h] - probes_per_bp) | dciss$stop[e] <= idcc$stop[h]) {
        score_gain = score_gain + nrow(gains_dciss)
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: how do I get it to work!